# Two Windows (plt.figure) in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I need two Windows that maintain  size and focus when data changes.
Size and focus are intended to be adjusted manually .

I managed myself to do what I want, but a Warning is shown :

"MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
ax1 = window1.add_subplot(111)".

Can someone explain what is wrong with my code?

Thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def Creo_ventana(primero,data):
   
    plt.ion()
  
        
    window1=plt.figure('WINDOW1') 
    ax1 = window1.add_subplot(111)
    window2=plt.figure('WINDOW2')  
    ax2 = window2.add_subplot(111)   
    
    y_min1, y_max1 = ax1.get_ylim()
    x_min1, x_max1 = ax1.get_xlim()
    size1=ax1.figure.get_size_inches() 
    y_min2, y_max2 = ax2.get_ylim()
    x_min2, x_max2 = ax2.get_xlim()
    size2=ax2.figure.get_size_inches()  
           
   
    if primero ==False:
        
        ax1.cla()
        ax1.set_xlim(x_min1, x_max1)
        ax1.set_ylim(y_min1, y_max1)
        ax1.figure.set_size_inches(size1)
        ax1.autoscale(False)
        ax1.autoscale_view (True,False,False)
        ax1.set_adjustable('box')
        
    ax1.plot(data) 
    window1.canvas.draw()
    window1.canvas.flush_events()       
        
    if primero ==False:        
        ax2.cla()
        ax2.set_xlim(x_min2, x_max2)
        ax2.set_ylim(y_min2, y_max2)
        ax2.figure.set_size_inches(size2)
        ax2.autoscale(False)
        ax2.autoscale_view (True,False,False)
        ax2.set_adjustable('box')       
 
    ax2.plot(data)        
    window2.canvas.draw()
    window2.canvas.flush_events()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    primero= True
    
    correr = 'y' 
    
    while correr =='y':
   
        data = np.random.rand(100)*10
      
        Creo_ventana(primero,data)
       
       
       
        primero= False
      
    
        correr=input ('otro? y/n :')

        if not correr == 'y':
            break
```